# Are we allowed to prove a theorem using that theorem itself?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm wondering, are we allowed to prove a theorem using that theorem itself? I can't give any specific examples, but from my professor's geometry notes it seems that a lot of theorems are proven assuming that we already know that it's true.

Comment: No. The aim of a proof is to derive a theorem from axioms or already proven theorem.

Comment: You *can* assume the negation of the theorem, to derive a contradiction (that leads to an indirect proof of the theorem).

Comment: @amWhy Ooo, that seems like a likely scenario, if the user mistook a proof by contradiction for "assuming that we already know that it's true."

Comment: No, we can't. We could prove anything like that. No truth is generated anywhere.

Comment: @rschwieb  Indeed, because it would proceed to assume $\lnot(p \to q) \equiv p \land \lnot q$.  So the OP might be mistaking the assumption of the premise (and negation of the conclusion) as assuming what is to be proven.  When in fact, what is to be proven is not $p$, but $p\to q$.

Comment: The method of "proof by induction" has such a flavor: There we assume the statement is true for some integer $k$ and then prove it is also true for $k+1$ (along with proving a base case such as $k=1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we can do this. Then:

**Theorem:** $1=0.$

**Proof:** Assume, $1=0.$ Then $1=0,$ hence proved.

In fact, proof of **every** statement would look like this and then you can prove that every conjecture is true.

Answer (score 3):

That would be [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question), or more generally circular reasoning. Not valid.

The truth of a theorem cannot be assumed before it is proven from axioms or previously proven theorems.

That said, I have my doubts that your teacher actually made this mistake so often.  While it is sometimes easy to accidentally introduce a cycle into your exposition, it is much less likely that you "do it a lot."

To make any headway, you'd have to actually give an example of what happened.

Comment: I concur with the "to make any headway" comment.  Note that one *can* assume the *negation* of a theorem, to derive a contradiction.  E.g., if a theorem is of the sort $p\to q$, one can assume the premise $p$ and the negation of $q$ (equivalent to the negation of the theorem), to derive a contradiction, thereby proving $p\to q$.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. That is essentially proof by induction. Once you prove a theorem for a limited case, you can then use that to prove the theorem for a more comprehensive case. If you can show that all possible cases are exhausted, then you will have proved the general theorem. In the case of mathematical induction, that is linked to the integers, but there are other ways to do it, such as showing that the progression of cases is bounded.